# Compile VLC on Lion

Tags: macos, development, vlc, internationalization

I am trying to compile VLC on my Mac along with [guide on wiki](http://wiki.videolan.org/OSXCompile). I am getting the

```
*** /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk does not exist, please install required SDK, or use export OSX_VERSION=10.6 ***
```

error, but I don't have a /Developer directory. Brew works fine and other compiling, too.

Am I somehow able to specify I want to build on 10.7 framework? I need to compile VLC for translating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To specify you want to build on 10.7, use

```
$ export OSX_VERSION=10.7
```

If you don't have a `/Developer` directory you probably have the new version of Xcode which installs itself directly into `/Applications`.

In that case the equivalent of the `/Developer` directory would be `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`, so look for a way to tell that to the build script.

Comment: Specifying the version is contained in the guide i liked. I would actually know concrete steps to get it work ;)

Comment: @Mailo: That guide says that to compile you run `$ ../extras/package/macosx/build.sh`. So just look what that does, and make it look in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` (or wherever your `Developer` directory is). Alternatively, just create a symlink at `/Developer` pointing to wherever your actual `Developer` directory is.